# What to do when Azure Websites and SQL Azure suffers a significant outage, like today?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

We use WAWS and WA SQL Azure. This morning the Northern Europe data centre suffered an outage for 1hr 50min. Basically we could not access our websites or databases. Now back, although still rumbling on.

I have to admit that I felt a little helpless.

- When would it reappear?
- What has caused it ?
- Who do I contact?

I have a feeling the cause is network related. May be the Load balancer ?

So what can we do when this happens, as usually MS engineers know about these "events" very quickly and are acting on them.

Some ideas I have had are:

1) Put a polite error page up if domain times out. Not sure how to do this. On an autoping service like pingdom or at the domain service where one defines the CNames. We reroute through to Azure. This communication is key to reassuring customers that issue is being sorted, and to prevent blank Azure 503 pages appearing.

2) Better information from Azure team, Decrease act of faith when service will be resumed.

3) Other actions required when this "event" happens.

I am sure this has impacted other Azure customers, and indeed other cloud customers. I suspect some are fellow Northern Europe users, and were impacted this morning like me. So what measures do you put in place to manage this issue, particularly around customer notice web pages which automatically appear.

EDIT1

Update from MS.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

SQL Databases - North Europe - Partial Performance Degradation

49 mins ago

Starting at 8/6/2014 6:56 UTC a subset of SQL customers may have experienced difficulty accessing their resources. A significant number of these SQL customers have already seen improvement. We have identified a potential root cause, and are working to restore service. The next update will be provided within two hours.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Partial Performance Degradation = no websites, no databases for us !

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Thank you for your comment on this. I tend to do this as I am indebted for any help that I get on SO, especially as folks take the time out of their busy lives to answer my question, and they are not obliged to do so. I do not take kindness for granted. However I do accept there is a recommended approach here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm still suffering from the SQL Azure outage.

Any external resources are not able to connect to the SQL Azure service, however internal resources on our account (e.g. WorkerRoles, WCFRoles, etc) are unaffected.

I don't know what the solution could be; it depends on your solution. I also host several Wordpress self-hosted websites on Azure and some are affected and some are not. The ones that are affected will not load and display a HTTP 502 error.

All I can suggest is a custom HTTP 502 page for your websites hosted on Azure and gracefully trap and handle any communication level exceptions (e.g. .NET's System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException).  in your hybrid applications that remotely access your SQL Azure database. *shrugs*

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully you will get full service shortly.

Comment: Thanks Sam, Microsoft say that full service is now resumed but the connectivity issues remain. This is not a good sign.

Comment: Just spoke with a colleague who suffered similarly, and then went to help another colleague, only to find that their cloud provider had gone down as well. So we all need a cloud plan. I think Electric Power Loss is a good model. When I ring up my local distributor, I get an expected SLA to fix, if the system has failed over to another part on the grid which takes a few minutes.

Comment: and... I know that it will be 8 hours, and I can make decisions. At the moment we seem to get minimal information on this. It could 30 mins, it could 5 hours. Not funny when customers are ringing up asking what is happening. Anyway, for us, we had minimal issues, and we are now focussing on a cloud outage plan, with an auto redirect apology page being most important. Not sure how to do this yet, as the failure may be way before the Web server. Also trying work out communications channels into MS.

Comment: Based on the communication from Microsoft, it seems they did not _know_ how long the outage would last.

Comment: "Also trying work out communications channels into MS"

That's the shocking thing that came out of this particular outage. If there's a problem, how are we - the developers using the service - supposed to know how long it will take? @John Saunders: You've got a point there that MS didn't know themselves, but in my case I had no remote access for 72 hours which was terribly inconvenient as it meant that my favoured way of working (via SQL in Management Studio) was not supported for three days.

Comment: I think this is a "work in progress". One thing that does need to happen from our end is to automatically display a professional and branded message page, say we know there is an issue, and it is being worked. Currently I have not come across a method of doing this in Azure, although it has been picked up as a good idea. So I am going to see if I can do it via the DNS server which is external to Azure. Currently I get bland white Error 500 type pages, which is not good enough for the professional image we are trying to portray.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good situation, something I always worry about too. There is a solution but it is not particularly cheap, but I guess that's what you pay for uptime.

a) Make sure you use Traffic Manager with a failover website in a totally different region. For example if your main site is Northern Europe then have the other site in West Europe. Chances of both data centers being down is low. You could add more failovers depending on your budget.

b) For you database you need to enable Geo-replication. If you are using Premium then you can make it a readonly online database. The failover website should point to this database. This will mean that your site is readonly for the period of the disruption, but at least your not dead. You can make this failover database your primary one if you want, so it is not readonly anymore. If you only have Standard database, like most of us poor souls, it works similarly but the backup database is 'offline'. Not sure what this means but I think it means you have to wait for MS to decide when things are bad enough to let you connect to the secondary database rather than it being always on.

Some info: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/12/spotlight-on-sql-database-active-geo-replication/

Comment: Thank you for this. We are looking into Geo-Replication, but feel it is a solution when bigger budgets allow. Nice to know that one can do it though. For the time being, the best thing we can do is automatically put up a branded, professional apology page when offline, and then automatically reverse when sites goes online again. Seems simple, but I have yet to find an approach to implement this. Thoughts?

Comment: Geo-Replication is a good idea in principle, but would not have resolved the OP's issue as there was a fault with Microsoft transport-security which also affected Geo-Replicated assets.